# Is there an update on Typing.Optional on python 3.9 or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: python, discord.py

While I was coding for help command for my bot in Discord.py, This function was not working as I expected.

```
def syntax(command):
    cmd_and_aliases = '|'.join([str(command), *command.aliases])
    params = []
    for key, value in command.params.items():
        if key not in ('self', 'ctx'):
            params.append(f'[{key}]' if 'NoneType' in str(value) else f'<{key}>')
    params = ' '.join(params)
    return f'`{cmd_and_aliases} {params}`'
```

What I wanted for this function was, returning and printing names and aliases to call up an discord command and what parts are necessary and what parts are not to run that command properly. As the Optional[str] in Typing can be translated as Union[str, None], What I wanted to get was what their could be and if it can be None, then it will be appended to the params list wrappend in square bracket, or else in angle bracket.

```
`name|aliases <necessary part> [optional part]`
```

This is what the function would originally would have returned, but both the necessary part and optional part are shown as wrapped in angle brackets.

```
@command(name='slap', aliases=['hit'])
async def slap_member(self, ctx, member: Member, *, reason: Optional[str] = 'for no reason'):
```

For example, for this command the result would have been like below.

```
slap|hit <Member> [reason]
```

But what I ended was getting was:

```
slap|hit <Member> <reason>.
```

Is there something I have done wrong or is there any update that would have made this function broken?
If there is something I did wrong, please help me by showing what I can do otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, can you please try to cut this down to the gist of the issue? It looks like most parts are to handle the discord wrapper. Do I read your code/question correctly that you are trying to format types based on their string representation, and Optional appears to have changed from being represented as a Union to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The "Why"

This behavior has indeed changed in 3.9; I believe [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/c1c7d8ead9eb214a6149a43e31a3213c52448877#diff-ddb987fca5f5df0c9a2f5521ed687919d70bb3d64eaeb8021f98833a2a716887R423) commit specifically is the cause. It looks like these changes *begun* in [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/40ded947f82683f0ed08144599a83d3a1ce719eb#diff-ddb987fca5f5df0c9a2f5521ed687919d70bb3d64eaeb8021f98833a2a716887R441) commit, but I believe the manifestation of your particular issue is due to the former.

I'm not deeply familiar with the plumbing of the `typing` module, but from what I can gather, the representation of `Optional` is now special-cased and **returns itself as-is**, i.e. `typing.Optional[x]` instead of "expanding" to `typing.Union[x, NoneType]`. They still have the same "type", however, but the important bit here is that their "type" has changed to [`_UnionGenericAlias`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0654c4c4cc54a325e878154f8b117159d0105cf7/Lib/typing.py#L907), whose `__repr__` is:

```
def __repr__(self):
    args = self.__args__
    if len(args) == 2:
        if args[0] is type(None):
            return f'typing.Optional[{_type_repr(args[1])}]'
        elif args[1] is type(None):
            return f'typing.Optional[{_type_repr(args[0])}]'
    return super().__repr__()
```

### Possible Solutions

First, I'd like to point out that you can use [`command.clean_params`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.clean_params) instead of `command.params` (which strangely isn't documented, from what I can tell). It functions the same, except it automatically excludes `self` and `ctx` so you don't have to check for it. I'll be using it in my solutions below.

**N.B.** `clean_params` returns parameters as [`inspect.Parameter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter) objects, so we have an **extra layer** to go through.

I came up with two possible solutions. The first is quite close to what you have, in that we do a simple string check for `typing.Optional`:

```
for key, value in command.clean_params.items():
    optional = str(value.annotation).startswith('typing.Optional')
    params.append(f'[{key}]' if optional else f'<{key}>')
```

Now I personally am not fond of string checks when it comes to determining types (Generics in this case), so I would opt for something a bit different. As described in [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/#parameters-to-generics-are-available-at-runtime), we can do runtime introspection on Generics, so let's take advantage of that.

```
for key, value in command.clean_params.items():
    anno = value.annotation
    try:
        optional = anno.__origin__ is Union and anno.__args__[1] is type(None)
    except AttributeError:
        optional = False
    params.append(f'[{key}]' if optional else f'<{key}>')
```

Another benefit of this approach is that it will work in Python 3.8 (and I *think* 3.7 as well), whereas the string checking version will obviously only work in 3.9. You *could* leverage `sys.version_info` and have multiple string checks, but that seems like too much hassle in comparison.

Comment: Tried both of the suggestions you got. First one actually didn't solve the problem. It worked as same as an original code.

Comment: Interesting, what do you get as the value of `str(value)`? What about the second method?

Comment: Uh...I forgot about talking about the second part. My bad.
The second part got an error called: AttributeError: 'Parameter' object has no attribute '__origin__'
I'll link the whole error message I got from trying second solution:
[link](https://pastebin.com/DpLDdLxz)

Comment: And after I saw your comment, I thought 'Why haven't I checked str(value) in the first place?' and proceeded to do it. str(value) was a format of 'key: type'.
So, Optional part was like 'key: Optional[type]' so, I just changed **NoneType** in `params.append(f'[{key}]' if 'NoneType' in str(value) else f'<{key}>')` to **Optional** and it solved the problem. Thanks for your help.

But still, I want to know how to solve this problem by using the second solution you gave to me. Because more I learn about coding, the more I would be better at it.

Comment: Ah, I missed the part in the docs for `clean_params` that says it returns `OrderedDict[str, inspect.Parameter]`. `Parameter` is from the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter) library, and lets you do introspection on objects. I'll update the answer to take this into account.

Comment: Just using params (not clean_params) gave an 'AttributeError: type object '_empty' has no attribute '__origin__' So I have done with 'clean_parmas' and got an error: 'AttributeError: type object 'Member' has no attribute '__origin__'.
Wonder if it can be solved by **try except AttributeError**?

Comment: Of course, I got so caught up in thinking about the `Optional` parameters, I forgot about the others, ha. Yes, annotations like `Member` aren't going to have `__origin__` and `__args__`, so catching `AttributeError` should be more than adequate to handle those. I'll update once more.

Comment: Worked for both situations when using just `command.params` and `command.clean_params`. (Responded late for some errors  I got, apart from your solution.)
Changing `typing.Optional` to just `Optional` in first solution will make your answer perfect.

Comment: In the last update, I changed the first solution as well; notice the use of `str(value.annotation)`. Just doing `str(value)` will give you the **string representation** of the `Parameter` object, which will be different (that's where your `'key: type'` from earlier came from).