# Making an automatic help command for my Discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How would I automatically get the usage and description from

```
@bot.command(usage='ping', desc='gets bots latency')
```

I tried `get_command()` `commands` `all_commands` but they did not return anything. I used another attempt with using a cog help command but still failed to work. Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please be sure to read [ask]; this isn't the place to get people to write your code for you. Can you include code that you've tried so far? What did you try that didn't work? Have you read all of the documentation for the [Command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command) class? Try searching for similar questions; someone [recently posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65771191/1208424) about doing something a bit similar, perhaps you can start there.

Comment: thanks the link to the exact doc was all i was asking for thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Discord's default help command, use `client.remove_command('help')`. This simply removes the default command "help" from your bot. With so, you can now replace and make your own, but you have to add them all manually.

I would also suggest using an embed as this also helps make the command look cleaner and organize the display of each command.

```
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):

    embed = discord.Embed(colour=0x7289DA, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
    embed.add_field(name='Help commands', value='Please refer to the commands listed below for commands available for use', inline=True)

    embed.add_field(name='command name', value='details about this command', inline=True)                                       
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Help commands")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey dear the is really easy.. You just need to write this :-

> @bot.command(usage='ping', desc='gets bots latency', help= 'Gets bot’s latency.')